# PHP Array Unknown Amount of Values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with an unknown amount of values, technically it can go on forever. But I would like to have a sum of values after 7 values. Example: sum of: $array[0], $array [7] and so forth. Starting with 0 and 7th, 14th, etc.

This issue has been a headache for me, I am a beginning php programmer.

```
$day1 = $array[0] + $array[7];
$day2 = $array[1] + $array[8];
$day3 = $array[2] + $array[9];
$day4 = $array[3] + $array[10];
$day5 = $array[4] + $array[11];
$day6 = $array[5] + $array[12];
$day7 = $array[6] + $array[13];
```

but then what if I have more values

```
$day1 = $array[0] + $array[7] + $array[13];
$day2 = $array[1] + $array[8] + $array[15];
$day3 = $array[2] + $array[9] + $array[16];
...
```

At this point it is no longer an issue of getting something done but rather a logical quest.

How to get the sum of elements after every 7 values?

Comment: Failed to parse question.

Comment: Apparently you should start by learning how to count. `$array[6]` is used twice in the first example, `$array[13]` is used twice in the second example. After that you can simple use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: Loop and use the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A PHP 5.6+ solution:

```
// Split the array into chunks of 7 items; the last chunk could be smaller
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 7);

// Iteratively apply a function to corresponding elements of each array
$result = array_map(
  // The mapping function receives 7 arguments, one from each chunk
  function(...$values) {          // Pack the arguments into a single array
    return array_sum($values);    // Return the sum of arguments
  },
  // Unpack $chunks into individual arguments (7 arrays)
  ...$chunks
);
```

Read more about the [arguments packing and unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) using what other languages call *"the **splat** operator"* (`...`). It was introduced in PHP 5.6.

#### A PHP 5.3+ solution

```
// Split the array into chunks of 7 items; the last chunk could be smaller
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 7);

// Prepare the arguments list for array_map() into $chunks
// Put the mapping function in front of the arrays
array_unshift($chunks, function() {
      // Return the sum of function arguments
      return array_sum(func_get_args());
});
// Call array_map() with the arguments stored in $chunks
$result = call_user_func_array('array_map', $chunks);
```

Read more about [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Anonymous functions were introduced in PHP 5.3

#### A solution that works with any PHP version

```
// Initialize the 7 sums with 0
$result = array_fill(0, 7, 0);
// Iterate over the array, add each item to the correct sum
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // $key % 7 distributes each value to the next index
    // starting over on each multiple of 7
    $result[$key % 7] += $value;
}
```

#### Final word

Use the first or the second solution to impress your friends or a recruiter. Use the last solution in production code; it is more clear and, for small input arrays (less than 100 items), it is faster than the other two. For larger arrays, the 5.6+ solution is faster, especially on PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

This way is not very elegant but i think the logic is here :

```
<?php

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7];
$day1=$day2=$day3=$day4=$day5=$day6=$day7=0;

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    switch ($key % 7){
        case 0: $day1 = $day1 + $value; break;
        case 1: $day2 = $day2 + $value; break;
        case 2: $day3 = $day3 + $value; break;
        case 3: $day4 = $day4 + $value; break;
        case 4: $day5 = $day5 + $value; break;
        case 5: $day6 = $day6 + $value; break;
        case 6: $day7 = $day7 + $value; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and this is what i was thinking about this morning but it is indeed not very elegant.

Comment: heh, interesting. I would nuke that in a code review but it's funny enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the sum of each seven following values:

```
//break the array into an array of arrays with 7 items each
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 7);

//map the items
$sums = array_map(function ($chunk) {
  //reduce the sum
  return array_reduce($chunk, 
    function ($sum, $val){ 
      return $sum + $val; 
    }, 0);
}, $chunks);
```

**update** due to the comment of @axiac, the above can be replaced by:

```
$sums = array_map(function ($chunk) { 
  return array_sum($chunk);
}, $chunks);
```

Please not that this does not deal with the case, that the last item in chunks may have less than seven items.

If you want to have the sum of the first and seventh, second eighth, third and ninth, etc:

```
$sums = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $sum = 0;
  for ($n = $i; $n < count($array); $n += 7) {
    $sum += $array[$n];
  }
  $sums[] = $sum;
}
```

note that this also does not deal with the case that `count($array) % 7` might not be zero.

Comment: `array_reduce($chunk, 
    function ($sum, $val){ 
      return $sum + $val; 
    }, 0)` is just a convoluted way to do what [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) does faster. And it doesn't produce the expected outcome, anyway.

Comment: @axiac haven't known about it…